# how to fix W: Target packages and Target DEP-11 error on ubuntu 19.04

Tags: repository, 19.04, add-apt-repository

when I tried to add a repository I'm getting these warning I don't know how to fix them. please help me on how to fix this warnings or errors.

What can I do?

```
(base) test@Batman:~$ sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ disco main'
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Get:2 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco InRelease [6,255 B]       
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Get:5 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco/main i386 Packages [42.1 kB]
Get:6 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages [39.5 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease [97.5 kB]     
Err:8 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                         
  Temporary failure resolving 'linux.teamviewer.com'
Err:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                      
  Temporary failure resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease [97.5 kB]   
Get:11 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease [88.8 kB]
Fetched 372 kB in 31s (11.9 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'linux.teamviewer.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
```

These are my repositories:

[image]

Comment: @Jim I don't know what are duplicates here. I have already gone through that answer couldn't find helpful for a newbie. If you could provide an answer and then mark it as duplicate would be really helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: @Jim I have provided a screenshot.

Comment: The suggested duplicate is exactly the same problem but with different software sources configured multiple times. The solutions are the same though. What's the problem in applying the solutions exactly? All suggestions seem easy to follow even for begginers.

Comment: Please note that the most voted answer has a new up-to-date method that does almost everything for you.

Comment: What I see from screenshot is there are two chrome repositories, uncheck one of them and run `apt update` again.